# Background threads ends automatically after 3 minutes in xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Whenever I am creating any thread to run in background for any application it stops automatically after 3 minutes. I am using Xamarin forms for building the iOS application. The issue exists only with the iOS and is working fine with other platforms. Below here is the code that I used to create the background thread:

```
nint taskID = UIKit.UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask( () => {Task.Factory.StartNew (() => syncData ());});
```

I have tried enabling the background mode and background fetch attributes in info.plist but using these could not solve the issue.

Please suggest me for the above issue.

Answer (score 1):

Background tasks from iOS7 will only give you 180 seconds. If your app not specified as "Music player/GPS navigation" and etc. 
As I understand from your code, you want to use background tasks for sync. For that background fetch works perfectly.
You can find a good tutorial here - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_ios_backgrounding_techniques/updating_an_application_in_the_background/

Comment: I had already visited the mentioned link and already enabled the background mode and background fetch attributes in info.plist but using these could not solve the issue

Comment: @SatyajeetGupta I hope that will help solve your problem :) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: I am trying to fetch data from API in xamarin forms.

 Also i am trying the "Perfrom Fetch with completionHandler" (override method) provide by ios and also enabling the background fetch. Here i set minimumbackgroundFetchTime of 15 mins but it never fired.

 It is only working when i use ios debuger for iphone and ios simulated background fetch debugger for simulator.